# how to store multiple array with different id in session?

Tags: php

need some help in session and array. Now it is saving only one array in the session, but i would like to save multiple array based on the id and save it into a session. the code below is where multiple user will use it so i want to save the id which they are connected together with the value so how can i do that?

```
$id = uniqid();
$value = $_POST["value];
$arr = [];
$arr = array("ID"=>$id, "value"=>$value);
$_SESSION["SaveArr"] = $arr;
```

after storing, i would like the user to edit their value based on their id in the array.

Comment: Please check if quotes are there in `$value = $_POST["value];`. It should be `$value = $_POST["value"];`

Comment: alright thanks for that though..  but is there any way to store multiple different array in a session?

Comment: @needhelp yes - it would be `$_SESSION['keyOne'] = array();` `$_SESSION['keyTwo'] = array();`

Comment: It appears that you are trying to have a single array with values across sessions - PHP doesn't work that way and each session has it's own $_SESSION array.



If you want a data store that contains data across sessions, you need to use a different solution, such as a database, key-value store like redis or memcached, or store them in files (not recommended) which each session would read.

Answer (score 0):

The session array works like any other PHP arrray. So if you want all your multiple arrays to be kept under `$_SESSION["SaveArr"]` then just add a `[]` like this

```
$_SESSION["SaveArr"][] = $arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this according to your code

```
$id    = uniqid();
$value = $_POST["value];
$arr   = [];
$arr   = array("ID"=>$id, "value"=>$value);
$_SESSION["SaveArr"][$id] = $arr;
```

So every time you get different array with different id.